# Potential energy function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy

I've been given

> "A particle of mass m moves under a force $F = −cx^5$, where $c$ is a positive constant. Determine the potential energy function."

I've obtained:

[image]

Is this correct? I've separted my lines with commas if you can see them.

Answer (score 1):

As long as its derivative with respect to x equals the force, your potential is defined, so your answer satisfies the requirements. However, you may want to add a constant to make the answer as general as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do self checks on these problems. In this case $F=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}$ So just take the negative derivative of the potential energy you got, and if it equals your original force, you got it.